# Capturing data regex

Tags: python, regex, split, regex-split

I am trying to create variables using text imported from `.doc` files. For the given text:

```
                  10         5,476,326.00    6              GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY          831 724-1011
                                                                                                  00000089
                                                            P O BOX 50085                     FAX 831 768-4021
                                                            WATSONVILLE CA  95077-5085
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  3
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    01     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           CAL STRIPE INC                                               ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           375 SOUTH G STREET
           SAN BERNARDINO CA  92410

           INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           23811 WASHINGTON AVE 110 317
           MURRIETA CA  92562

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           8257 COMPTON
           LOS ANGELES CA  90001

           MURPHY INDUSTRIAL COATING INC                                ITEM 47
           2704  GUNERLY AVENUE
           SIGNAL HILL C  90755
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  4
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    03     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                               ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           VENTURA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           LUNDENE PAINTING                                             ITEM 47
           FONTANA CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    10     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                           ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59 (PARTIAL)
           VENTURA CA

           FFB VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION                                    ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           LIVERMORE CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANGELES CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEM INC                                ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  5
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    09     INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           MURIETTA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANELES CA

           MARINA LANDSCAPE INC                                         EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           ANAHEIM CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEMS INC                               ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC                                    STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           SUN VALLEY CA

           TOOMEY INDUSTRIES                                            TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           LONG BEACH CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    04     CAL STRIPE INC                                               STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           SAN BERNARDINO CA

           HUBBS CONSTRUCTION                                           ITEMS 26, 27 AND 57 THRU 59 (PARTIAL)
           YUCAIPA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ELECTRICAL (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANGELES CA                                                                                                                                                                                           BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  7
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    02     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                             ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           COOPER ENGINEERING INCORORATED                               ITEMS 60 THRU 65
           TUSTIN CA

           HIGHLIGHT ELECTRIC                                           ITEMS 2 AND 68 THRU 70 (PARTIAL)
           P O BOX 7339
           RIVERSIDE CA  92513

           P R S I                                                      ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           P O BOX 1266
           RIVERSIDE CA  92501

           R DUGAN                                                      ITEMS 31, 46, 51 AND 56 (PARTIAL)
           6157 MARLATT STREET
           MIRA LOMA CA  91752

           STATEWIDE SAFETY AND SIGNS                                   ITEMS 12, 14, 16, 19 AND 57 (PARTIAL)
           POWAY CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES                                ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           P O BOX 12833
           SCOTTSDALE AZ  85267

 CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  9
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    05     SULLY MILLER                                                 ITEMS 40 THRU 45
           VICTORVILLE CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    06     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27 AND 57 THRU 59 (PARTIAL)
           VENTURA CA

           F B D VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION INC                              ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           LIVERMORE CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                C O N T R A C T   P R O P O S A L   O F   L O W   B I D D E R                 PAGE 10
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ITEM      ITEM                                                   UNIT OF     ESTIMATED
      NO.      CODE                  ITEM DESCRIPTION                 MEASURE     QUANTITY          BID              AMOUNT
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       1     070012      PROGRESS SCHEDULE (CRITICAL PATH METHOD)       LS     LUMP SUM            4,000.00         4,000.00
       2     070018      TIME-RELATED OVERHEAD                          WDAY        150            1,000.00       150,000.00
```

I am trying to build a dataset of the following form (with all bidder IDs as in the text):

| bidder-id | number_subcontractors | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 5 | 26, 27, 58, 59, 15, 66, 67, 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 47 |
| 03 | 3 | 26, 27, 58, 59, 68, 69, 47 |

I think we can do by:

- **splitting the text** into different bidder-id texts

**text 1:**

```
_________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    01     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           CAL STRIPE INC                                               ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           375 SOUTH G STREET
           SAN BERNARDINO CA  92410

           INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           23811 WASHINGTON AVE 110 317
           MURRIETA CA  92562

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           8257 COMPTON
           LOS ANGELES CA  90001

           MURPHY INDUSTRIAL COATING INC                                ITEM 47
           2704  GUNERLY AVENUE
           SIGNAL HILL C  90755
```

**text 2:**

```
    03     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                               ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           VENTURA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           LUNDENE PAINTING                                             ITEM 47
           FONTANA CA
```

- Then **capture each bidder-id specific string as a dataset**. So, the number of subcontractors would be the number of observations for each bidder-id, and we can also concate all the item numbers.

I believe I am struggling at step 1 (splitting the big string into the small strings we want). Right now, I have the following code:

```
# imports
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import docx2txt
import textract
import antiword

# setting directory
os.chdir('/Users/aartimalik/Documents/GitHub/revenue_procurement/pdfs/small-test')

# import text
txt = " 
                  10         5,476,326.00    6              GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY          831 724-1011
                                                                                                  00000089
                                                            P O BOX 50085                     FAX 831 768-4021
                                                            WATSONVILLE CA  95077-5085
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  3
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    01     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           CAL STRIPE INC                                               ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           375 SOUTH G STREET
           SAN BERNARDINO CA  92410

           INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           23811 WASHINGTON AVE 110 317
           MURRIETA CA  92562

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           8257 COMPTON
           LOS ANGELES CA  90001

           MURPHY INDUSTRIAL COATING INC                                ITEM 47
           2704  GUNERLY AVENUE
           SIGNAL HILL C  90755
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  4
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    03     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                               ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           VENTURA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           LUNDENE PAINTING                                             ITEM 47
           FONTANA CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    10     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                           ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59 (PARTIAL)
           VENTURA CA

           FFB VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION                                    ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           LIVERMORE CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANGELES CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEM INC                                ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  5
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    09     INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           MURIETTA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANELES CA

           MARINA LANDSCAPE INC                                         EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           ANAHEIM CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEMS INC                               ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC                                    STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           SUN VALLEY CA

           TOOMEY INDUSTRIES                                            TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           LONG BEACH CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    04     CAL STRIPE INC                                               STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           SAN BERNARDINO CA

           HUBBS CONSTRUCTION                                           ITEMS 26, 27 AND 57 THRU 59 (PARTIAL)
           YUCAIPA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ELECTRICAL (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANGELES CA
 CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  6
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    04     PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEM INC                                GRINDING (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION                                        ITEMS 60 AND 61 (PARTIAL)
           OAKLAND CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES                                PAINTING (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    08     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 57 THRU 59
           VENTURA CA

           CAL STRIPE INC                                               ITEMS 15, 22, 23, 66 AND 67
           SAN BERNARDINO CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           MARINA LANDSCAPE INC                                         ITEM 38
           ANAHEIM CA

           MATICH CORPORATION                                           ITEMS 40 THRU 43
           SAN BERNARDINO CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES                                ITEM 47
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  7
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    02     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                             ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           COOPER ENGINEERING INCORORATED                               ITEMS 60 THRU 65
           TUSTIN CA

           HIGHLIGHT ELECTRIC                                           ITEMS 2 AND 68 THRU 70 (PARTIAL)
           P O BOX 7339
           RIVERSIDE CA  92513

           P R S I                                                      ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           P O BOX 1266
           RIVERSIDE CA  92501

           R DUGAN                                                      ITEMS 31, 46, 51 AND 56 (PARTIAL)
           6157 MARLATT STREET
           MIRA LOMA CA  91752

           STATEWIDE SAFETY AND SIGNS                                   ITEMS 12, 14, 16, 19 AND 57 (PARTIAL)
           POWAY CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES                                ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           P O BOX 12833
           SCOTTSDALE AZ  85267


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    07     C AND W FENCE                                                ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           VENTURA CA
 CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  8
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    07     COOPER ENGINEERING INCORPORATED                              ITEMS 60 THRU 65
           TUSTIN CA

           MOORE ELECTRIC                                               ITEMS 68 AND 69
           CORONA CA

           PRS CONSTRUCTION                                             ITEM 29
           RIVERSIDE CA

           STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC                                    ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           SUN VALLEY CA

           TRAFFIC LOOPS                                                ITEM 69
           ANAHEIM CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    05     INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65
           MURRIETA CA

           J F L  ELECTRIC INC                                          ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEMS INC                               ITEM 28
           RIVERSIDE CA

           PERRIS TRAFFIC CONTROL                                       ITEMS 12 AND 13 (PARTIAL)
           MURRIETA CA

           STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC                                    ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           SUN VALLEY CA
 CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  9
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    05     SULLY MILLER                                                 ITEMS 40 THRU 45
           VICTORVILLE CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    06     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27 AND 57 THRU 59 (PARTIAL)
           VENTURA CA

           F B D VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION INC                              ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           LIVERMORE CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                C O N T R A C T   P R O P O S A L   O F   L O W   B I D D E R                 PAGE 10
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     ITEM      ITEM                                                   UNIT OF     ESTIMATED
      NO.      CODE                  ITEM DESCRIPTION                 MEASURE     QUANTITY          BID              AMOUNT
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

       1     070012      PROGRESS SCHEDULE (CRITICAL PATH METHOD)       LS     LUMP SUM            4,000.00         4,000.00
       2     070018      TIME-RELATED OVERHEAD                          WDAY        150            1,000.00       150,000.00 "

# splitting
txt = txt.split('DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED')
del txt[0]

data = txt[0]
```

Any help or lead would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

[Reference regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8LmQyZ/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `document.txt` contains your document, you can try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KJ5qPd/1)):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

with open("document.txt", "r") as f_in:
    document = f_in.read()

data = []
for id_, group in re.findall(
    r"(?s)BIDDER ID\D+DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED\D+(\d+)(.*?)(?=BIDDER ID|-{5,}|\Z)",
    document,
):
    items = re.findall(r"ITEMS? (.*)", group)
    data.append(
        {
            "bidder-id": id_,
            "number_subcontractors": group.count('\n\n'),
            "items": ", ".join(
                i.replace(" (PARTIAL)", "").replace(" AND", ",").strip() for i in items
            ),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   bidder-id  number_subcontractors                                                                                  items
0         01                      5                                     26, 27, 58, 59, 15, 66, 67, 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 47
1         03                      3                                                             26, 27, 58, 59, 68, 69, 47
2         10                      5                                             26, 27, 58, 59, 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 28, 47
3         09                      7                                                         60 THRU 65, 68 THRU 69, 28, 47
4         04                      3                                                                     26, 27, 57 THRU 59
5         04                      3                                                                                 60, 61
6         08                      6                             57 THRU 59, 15, 22, 23, 66, 67, 68, 69, 38, 40 THRU 43, 47
7         02                      7  26, 27, 58, 59, 60 THRU 65, 2, 68 THRU 70, 28, 31, 46, 51, 56, 12, 14, 16, 19, 57, 47
8         07                      1                                                                         26, 27, 58, 59
9         07                      5                                                 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 29, 15, 66, 67, 69
10        05                      5                                             60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 28, 12, 13, 15, 66, 67
11        05                      1                                                                             40 THRU 45
12        06                      3                                                     26, 27, 57 THRU 59, 60 THRU 65, 47
```

Comment: Clarificatory question: can we capture the DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED values that do not start with "ITEM" -? For example, it could be any string not beginning with ITEM. 

In this (https://regex101.com/r/KG6eUc/1), we would ideally want to capture "STRING TESTING OK," "YES IM TESTING STRING," and "KEEP TESTING FOREVER" as well. Right now, these values are blank in the output dataset. Thanks for your time!