# Capturing data regex python

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to create variables using text imported from `.doc` files. For the given text:

```
                  10         5,476,326.00    6              GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY          831 724-1011
                                                                                                  00000089
                                                            P O BOX 50085                     FAX 831 768-4021
                                                            WATSONVILLE CA  95077-5085
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  3
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    01     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59, STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           CAL STRIPE INC                                               ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           375 SOUTH G STREET
           SAN BERNARDINO CA  92410

           INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           23811 WASHINGTON AVE 110 317
           MURRIETA CA  92562

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           8257 COMPTON
           LOS ANGELES CA  90001

           MURPHY INDUSTRIAL COATING INC                                ITEM 47
           2704  GUNERLY AVENUE
           SIGNAL HILL C  90755
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  4
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    03     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                               ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           VENTURA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           LUNDENE PAINTING                                             ITEM 47
           FONTANA CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    10     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                           ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59 (PARTIAL)
           VENTURA CA

           FFB VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION                                    ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           LIVERMORE CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANGELES CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEM INC                                ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  5
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    09     INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           MURIETTA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANELES CA

           MARINA LANDSCAPE INC                                         EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           ANAHEIM CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEMS INC                               ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC                                    STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           SUN VALLEY CA

           TOOMEY INDUSTRIES                                            TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           LONG BEACH CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
```

I am trying to build a dataset of the following form (with all bidder IDs as in the text):

| bidder-id | number_subcontractors | items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 5 | 26, 27, 58, 59, STRIPING (PARTIAL), 15, 66, 67, 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 47 |
| 03 | 3 | 26, 27, 58, 59, 68, 69, 47 |

Many thanks to @Andrej Keseley, the following code captures most of what we want in the dataset.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

document = "

                  10         5,476,326.00    6              GRANITE CONSTRUCTION COMPANY          831 724-1011
                                                                                                  00000089
                                                            P O BOX 50085                     FAX 831 768-4021
                                                            WATSONVILLE CA  95077-5085
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  3
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    01     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC                         ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59, STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           2419 PALMA DRIVE
           VENTURA CA  93003

           CAL STRIPE INC                                               ITEMS 15, 66 AND 67
           375 SOUTH G STREET
           SAN BERNARDINO CA  92410

           INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           23811 WASHINGTON AVE 110 317
           MURRIETA CA  92562

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           8257 COMPTON
           LOS ANGELES CA  90001

           MURPHY INDUSTRIAL COATING INC                                ITEM 47
           2704  GUNERLY AVENUE
           SIGNAL HILL C  90755
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  4
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    03     C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                               ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59
           VENTURA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69
           LOS ANGELES CA

           LUNDENE PAINTING                                             ITEM 47
           FONTANA CA


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    10     C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC                           ITEMS 26, 27, 58 AND 59 (PARTIAL)
           VENTURA CA

           FFB VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION                                    ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           LIVERMORE CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 AND 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANGELES CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEM INC                                ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
          08-0C8104                                                                                                BID245
          08-SBD-15-4                                                                                              PAGE  5
          11/21/08                                                                                                 11/26/08
                                            L I S T   O F   S U B C O N T R A C T O R S


 BIDDER ID NAME AND ADDRESS                                            DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED
 _________ ____________________________________________________________ ____________________________________________________________

    09     INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS                                      ITEMS 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL)
           MURIETTA CA

           J F L ELECTRIC INC                                           ITEMS 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL)
           LOS ANELES CA

           MARINA LANDSCAPE INC                                         EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           ANAHEIM CA

           PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEMS INC                               ITEM 28 (PARTIAL)
           RIVERSIDE CA

           STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC                                    STRIPING (PARTIAL)
           SUN VALLEY CA

           TOOMEY INDUSTRIES                                            TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL)
           LONG BEACH CA

           VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC                            ITEM 47 (PARTIAL)
           SCOTTSDALE AZ
"

data = []
for id_, group in re.findall(
    r"(?s)BIDDER ID\D+DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED\D+(\d+)(.*?)(?=BIDDER ID|-{5,}|\Z)",
    document,
):
    items = re.findall(r"ITEMS? (.*)", group)
    data.append(
        {
            "bidder-id": id_,
            "number_subcontractors": group.count('\n\n'),
            "items": ", ".join(
                i.replace(" (PARTIAL)", "").replace(" AND", ",").strip() for i in items
            ),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   bidder-id  number_subcontractors                                                                                  items
0         01                      5                                     26, 27, 58, 59, 15, 66, 67, 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 47
1         03                      3                                                             26, 27, 58, 59, 68, 69, 47
2         10                      5                                             26, 27, 58, 59, 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 28, 47
3         09                      7                                                         60 THRU 65, 68 THRU 69, 28, 47
4         04                      3                                                                     26, 27, 57 THRU 59
5         04                      3                                                                                 60, 61
6         08                      6                             57 THRU 59, 15, 22, 23, 66, 67, 68, 69, 38, 40 THRU 43, 47
7         02                      7  26, 27, 58, 59, 60 THRU 65, 2, 68 THRU 70, 28, 31, 46, 51, 56, 12, 14, 16, 19, 57, 47
8         07                      1                                                                         26, 27, 58, 59
9         07                      5                                                 60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 29, 15, 66, 67, 69
10        05                      5                                             60 THRU 65, 68, 69, 28, 12, 13, 15, 66, 67
11        05                      1                                                                             40 THRU 45
12        06                      3                                                     26, 27, 57 THRU 59, 60 THRU 65, 47
```

But it does not capture strings that do not start with `ITEMS` (like `STRIPING (PARTIAL)`). I am not sure if we can do this by only using regex in the current code. Maybe splitting text would help? I am not sure, still trying to figure it out.

Any help or lead would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

[Reference regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8LmQyZ/1)

[Reference Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486143/capturing-data-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, i think this might work:

In your code just replace

```py
items = re.findall(r"ITEMS? (.*)", group)
```

with

```py
items = re.findall(r"\w {3,}(.*)", group)
```

and then some minor changes to the `data.append`

leaving you with this:

```py
data = []
for id_, group in re.findall(
    r"(?s)BIDDER ID\D+DESCRIPTION OF PORTION OF WORK SUBCONTRACTED\D+(\d+)(.*?)(?=BIDDER ID|-{5,}|\Z)",
    document,
):
    items = re.findall(r"\w {3,}(.*)", group)
    data.append(
        {
            "bidder-id": id_,
            "number_subcontractors": group.count('\n\n'),
            "items": ", ".join(
                i.replace(" AND", ",").replace("ITEMS ", "").replace("ITEM", "").strip() for i in items
            ),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

which then results the items column for bidder id 09 looking like:

```
60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL), 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL), EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL), 28 (PARTIAL), STRIPING (PARTIAL), TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL), 47 (PARTIAL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be interesting to load all tabled data from the document text into the data frame (so including the subcontractor's name and address), so that you can then retrieve from it what you want.

The summary information can then be extracted using panda's `groupby` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def load(document):
    data = []
    # Identify lines of interest by specific column layout
    res = re.findall(r"^ (.{8})  (\S.{0,60}$|\S.{58})(?:  (\S.*$))?", document, re.M)
    for a, b, c in res:
        bidder = a.strip() or bidder
        if c: # new subcontractor
            data.append({
                "bidder-id": bidder, 
                "items": re.sub(r" AND|ITEM(S )?", ",", c).strip(" ,"),
                "name": b.strip(),
                "address": ""
            })
        else: # continuation with address
            data[-1]["address"] = (data[-1]["address"] + "\n").lstrip() + b.strip()
    return pd.DataFrame(data)


subcontractors = load(document)
summary = subcontractors.groupby("bidder-id").agg(
           {"items": ", ".join, "name": "count"}
          ).rename(columns={"name": "number_subcontractors"})
```

For the example document, the `summary` dataframe will have:

| bidder-id | items | number_subcontractors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 26, 27, 58, 59, STRIPING (PARTIAL), 15, 66, 67, 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL), 68, 69, 47 | 5 |
| 03 | 26, 27, 58, 59, 68, 69, 47 | 3 |
| 09 | 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL), 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL), EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL), 28 (PARTIAL), STRIPING (PARTIAL), TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL), 47 (PARTIAL) | 7 |
| 10 | 26, 27, 58, 59 (PARTIAL), 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL), 68, 69 (PARTIAL), 28 (PARTIAL), 47 (PARTIAL) | 5 |

Just for info, the `subcontractors` dataframe looks like this:

| bidder-id | items | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 26, 27, 58, 59, STRIPING (PARTIAL) | C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTIES INC | 2419 PALMA DRIVE VENTURA CA 93003 |
| 01 | 15, 66, 67 | CAL STRIPE INC | 375 SOUTH G STREET SAN BERNARDINO CA 92410 |
| 01 | 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL) | INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS | 23811 WASHINGTON AVE 110 317 MURRIETA CA 92562 |
| 01 | 68, 69 | J F L ELECTRIC INC | 8257 COMPTON LOS ANGELES CA 90001 |
| 01 | 47 | MURPHY INDUSTRIAL COATING INC | 2704 GUNERLY AVENUE SIGNAL HILL C 90755 |
| 03 | 26, 27, 58, 59 | C W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC | VENTURA CA |
| 03 | 68, 69 | J F L ELECTRIC INC | LOS ANGELES CA |
| 03 | 47 | LUNDENE PAINTING | FONTANA CA |
| 10 | 26, 27, 58, 59 (PARTIAL) | C AND W CONSTRUCTION SPECIALTY INC | VENTURA CA |
| 10 | 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL) | FFB VANGUARD CONSTRUCTION | LIVERMORE CA |
| 10 | 68, 69 (PARTIAL) | J F L ELECTRIC INC | LOS ANGELES CA |
| 10 | 28 (PARTIAL) | PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEM INC | RIVERSIDE CA |
| 10 | 47 (PARTIAL) | VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC | SCOTTSDALE AZ |
| 09 | 60 THRU 65 (PARTIAL) | INTEGRITY REBAR PLACERS | MURIETTA CA |
| 09 | 68 THRU 69 (PARTIAL) | J F L ELECTRIC INC | LOS ANELES CA |
| 09 | EROSION CONTROL (PARTIAL) | MARINA LANDSCAPE INC | ANAHEIM CA |
| 09 | 28 (PARTIAL) | PAVEMENT RECYCLING SYSTEMS INC | RIVERSIDE CA |
| 09 | STRIPING (PARTIAL) | STERNDAHL ENTERPRISES INC | SUN VALLEY CA |
| 09 | TRAFFIC CONTROL (PARTIAL) | TOOMEY INDUSTRIES | LONG BEACH CA |
| 09 | 47 (PARTIAL) | VISUAL POLLUTION TECHNOLOGIES INC | SCOTTSDALE AZ |